# remove description lines and add time to the first column

Tags: date, awk, extract

AWk experts, I have a file as descried below and I wonder if it is possible to easily convert it to the form that I want:

The file containing multiple variables over one month (one observance ONLY in one day, but some days may be missing). The format for each day is the same except the date/value. However there is some description lines (containing words and numbers) at the end of each day, and the number of description lines varies among different days.

```
    KBO BTA Observations at 12Z 01 Feb 2020
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   PRES   HGHT   TEMP   DWPT   RELH   MIXR   DRCT   SKNT   THTA   THTE   THTV
    hPa     m      C      C      %    g/kg    deg   knot     K      K      K
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1000.0     92
  925.0    765
  850.0   1516
  754.0   2546   13.0    9.3     78   9.85    150      2  310.2  340.6  312.0
  752.0   2569   14.0    9.2     73   9.80    149      2  311.5  342.0  313.4
  700.0   3173  -9.20    7.5     89   9.38    120      6  312.6  341.9  314.4
Station information and sounding indices
                          Station elevation: 2546.0
                               Lifted index: 1.83
Pres [hPa] of the Lifted Condensation Level: 693.42
              1000 hPa to 500 hPa thickness: 5798.00
Precipitable water [mm] for entire sounding: 21.64
8022 KBO BTA Observations at 00Z 02 Feb 2020
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   PRES   HGHT   TEMP   DWPT   RELH   MIXR   DRCT   SKNT   THTA   THTE   THTV
    hPa     m      C      C      %    g/kg    deg   knot     K      K      K
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1000.0     97
  925.0    758
  850.0   1515
  753.0   2546   10.8    6.8     76   8.30    190      3  307.9  333.4  309.5
  750.0   2580   12.6    7.9     73   8.99    186      3  310.2  338.1  311.9
```

Here is what I want:  remove all the description lines and read the date/time information and put it as the first column.

```
Time  PRES   HGHT   TEMP   DWPT   RELH   MIXR   DRCT   SKNT   THTA   THTE   THTV
20200201t12Z  754.0   2546   13.0    9.3     78   9.85    150      2  310.2  340.6  312.0
20200201t12Z  752.0   2569   14.0    9.2     73   9.80    149      2  311.5  342.0  313.4
20200201t12Z  700.0   3173   -9.2    7.5     89   9.38    120      6  312.6  341.9  314.4
20200202t00Z  753.0   2546   10.8    6.8     76   8.30    190      3  307.9  333.4  309.5
20200202t00Z  750.0   2580   12.6    7.9     73   8.99    186      3  310.2  338.1  311.9
```

Any help is appreciated.

Kelly

Comment: Is there a pattern that would always distinguish the description lines from the observation data? Is it possible, among all edge cases, that a description can contain five numbers and no upper or lower case letters?
Is the observation data file space- or tab-delimited?
Are "site_ID" & "site_name" placeholders or constant strings that indicate a new observation?

Comment: If those `...` lines don't actually exist in your data then get rid of them from your example. Simply provide some concise, testable sample input and expected output that demonstrates your needs and we can test a potential solution against. Also add what you'd tried so far yourself.

Comment: Also - are those dates correct in your output? The first date in your input is `01 Jan 2020` and the second is `02 Jan 2020` while the first date in your output is `20200201` so is that output date in YYYYDDMM format instead of YYYYMMDD and associated with the 2nd date? If so then that means the date lines in your input are associated with the data that comes before rather than after them, right? Or is the first date in your output actually supposed to be `20200101`? And is that YYYYMMDD or YYYYDDMM format?

Comment: On the date line, do you literally have "site_ID" or it will be replaced by some real id value?

Comment: @karakfa, it can be replaced.

Comment: @EdMorton, you are right. The date should be the same.I just edited the post.  I used a tedious way with some manual work:  first I used "awk 'NF==11' feb.txt > 202002.txt"(there are actually 11 columns in the data and fortunately the description lines is either less than 11 or more than 11 columns), and I then use "csplit -z" to split 202002.txt into 28 files (for Feb), and then rename those files based on their date. But this will not work if one of the description line also has 11 columns.ate should be the same.

Comment: @proteome, unfortunately the description has both words and numbers. Some line starts with words and some starts with numbers. Yes "site_ID" & "site_name" are the same in each file.

Comment: Everywhere you have placeholder strings like `site_ID` in your example replace it with an sample value of such a string (make one up, it doesn't have to be your real data, just look like your real data) so we don't help you create a solution that keys off those strings that aren't really present in your data. Right now we don't know what parts of your input are real strings or placeholders that won't actually be present in your real data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this...

```
$ awk 'function m(x) 
         {return sprintf("%02d",int(index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",x)-1)/3+1)} 

 NR==1   {print "time PRES TEMP WDIR WSPD RELH"} 
 /^-+$/  {f=!f} 
 f       {date=p[n] m(p[n-1]) p[n-2]} 
!f       {n=split($0,p)}  
 NF==11 && !/[^ 0-9.-]/ {print date,$0}' file | column -t

time      PRES  TEMP  WDIR  WSPD  RELH
20200201  1000  10    230   5     90
20200201  900   9     200   6     85
20200201  800   9     100   6     87
20200202  1000  9.2   233   5     90
20200202  900   9.1   200   4     80
20200202  800   9     176   2     80
```

**Explanation**
function just returns the month number from the month string by looking up the index of and converting to formatted number

`f` keeps track of the dashed lines so that from the previous line we can parse the date,

finally to find the data lines the heuristic is number of fields and no non-number signs (digits, spaces, dots or negative signs).

Comment: Took at bit to psych out the toggle (the font in my browser made `!f` look like `lf`), but looking at it in an editor cleared it up. This one took some thought.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin  If I had more time it would be shorter..  Some complexity is required to find the date header and data. And there is month conversion...

Comment: I thought it was a great approach. After seeing both you and Ed had answered, I knew there wasn't any use in a 3rd answer, but I always go though and understand the answers.

Comment: @karakfa, thank you for help. For some reason, I tried to copy your script but only print the header line "time      PRES  TEMP  WDIR  WSPD  RELH".

Comment: change `NF==5` to `NF==11` or whatever number of fields you have in your data section.

Comment: @karakfa, Thank you. There is still a problem though. It only print the lines when all data are positive and it will skip to next day whenever negative number appear. I just updated the example by putting a negative number in.

Comment: @karakfa, unbelievable...it works perfectly now! Thank you so much. Sorry to ask for more, would you please provide more explanation to the script? It seems so advanced to me.

Comment: @karakfa, sorry to ask more things: how to add the time cycle like"12Z" as appeared on the top of the input? Because not all files have the same cycle. I had edited my post above.

Comment: that will be `p[n-3]` field, just append to date mimicking how it's done.  Not sure where the "t" comes from. If fixed you can insert it there as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^-+$/ && ( ((++dashCnt) % 2) == 1 ) {
    mthNr = (index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",p[n-1])+2)/3
    time = sprintf("%04d%02d%02d", p[n], mthNr, p[n-2])
}
/^[[:upper:][:space:]]+$/ && !doneHdr++ { print "Time", $0 }
/^[0-9.[:space:]]+$/ { print time, $0 }
{ n = split($0,p) }
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file | column -t
Time      PRES  TEMP  WDIR  WSPD  RELH
20200001  1000  10    230   5     90
20200001  900   9     200   6     85
20200001  800   9     100   6     87
20200002  1000  9.2   233   5     90
20200002  900   9.1   200   4     80
20200002  800   9     176   2     80
```

Comment: Always a pleasure.

Comment: @Ed, thank you for help, Unfortunately for some reason it didn't print all lines.I guess I didn't give enough information. The script is far beyond my ability to make any change, so I just edit my previous post, maybe you can find the problem. Would you please give more explanation to each line?